# Subtract number from enumerated file names

Tags: bash, file, ubuntu

I have some a folder with enumerated files with names such as FILE_001.dat. One of the files has a mistake though so I would like to take that out of the folder and rename the following ones such that I still have them all sequential without any gaps in the numbering. Does anyone know hoe to do that via bash?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the wrong file is FILE_030.dat and you have 300 files. Then what you could do is the following

```
#!/bin/bash
mv FILE_030.dat some_directory/
for ((i=31; i<=300; i++))
do
   filename=FILE_`printf "%03d" ${i}`.dat
   if [ -e ${filename} ]
   then
       newi=$(( $i - 1 ))
       newfilename=FILE_`printf "%03d" ${newi}`.dat
       # This should not happen
       if [ -e ${newfilename} ]
       then
           echo Error moving file ${filename} to ${newfilename}: ${newfilename} exists
           exit
       else
           mv ${filename} ${newfilename}
       fi
   fi
done
```

If your files have names like FILE_00030.dat, i.e., with 5 digits, then you have to change `%03d` to `0%5d` in the code above.
As a safety a check, the script above stops when it renamed file already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ([Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean) code, after setting `badfile` and `bad_files_dir` appropriately:

```
#! /bin/bash

badfile=FILE_013.dat            # The bad file to be moved out
bad_files_dir=../badfilesdir    # The directory to receive the bad file

movedfile=
for file in FILE_[0-9][0-9][0-9].dat ; do
    if [[ -n $movedfile ]] ; then
        mv -- "$file" "$movedfile"
        movedfile=$file
    elif [[ $file == "$badfile" ]] ; then
        mv -- "$file" "$bad_files_dir"
        movedfile=$file
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!